# Form_load selects line (richtextbox), form temporarily loses focus, returns back with entire richtextbox selected

Tags: vb.net, select, richtextbox, textselection, selectionchanged

I have a form_load thats selecting a string in a RTB and it works perfectly, makes the line I specify highlighted yellow and all other lines untouched. when I click a button and load another form and use it then close it, the original  form now  has the entirety of its contents highlighted yellow. I tried adding rtb.DeselectAll() after the lines of code that select, but nothing seems to work.

I appreciate any and all suggestions. thanks in advance

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

ReminderList.SelectionStart = ReminderList.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(0)
ReminderList.SelectionLength = ReminderList.Lines(Globalvar.ReminderCount 1).Length
ReminderList.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow
Call FillOutCal()

End Sub
```

UPDATE: What Jim has said I am already aware of, the problem is that when I use another form and revisit the original form, the yellow selected portion has changed to encompass the whole rich text box. Here is the code for a Save button that brings back the main form with the selection bug:

```
Private Sub SaveButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click

    FormDesktop.ReminderList.DeselectAll()

    If ItemName.Text = Nothing Then
        Dim newerror As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Missing some information to complete the entry, make sure everything is filled out.", _
                                                       "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf ReminderRadio.Checked = False And TaskRadio.Checked = False And IdeaRadio.Checked = False Then
        Dim newerror As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Missing some information to complete the entry, make sure everything is filled out.", _
                                              "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Dim TypeOfIdea As Integer

    If ReminderRadio.Checked = True Then
        FormDesktop.ReminderList.Text += vbCrLf
        TypeOfIdea = 1
        Globalvar.ReminderCount += 1
    ElseIf TaskRadio.Checked = True Then
        FormDesktop.TaskList.Text += vbCrLf
        TypeOfIdea = 2
        Globalvar.TaskCount += 1
    Else
        FormDesktop.IdeaList.Text += vbCrLf
        TypeOfIdea = 3
        Globalvar.IdeaCount += 1
    End If

    Dim NameOfItem As String = ItemName.Text

    Dim DueMonth As Integer = DateTimePick.Value.Month
    Dim DueDay As Integer = DateTimePick.Value.Day
    Dim DueYear As Integer = DateTimePick.Value.Year

    Dim SubMonth As Integer = DateTime.Now.Month
    Dim SubDay As Integer = DateTime.Now.Day
    Dim SubYear As Integer = DateTime.Now.Year

    Dim DueHour As Integer = Hour.Value
    Dim DueMinute As Integer = Minute.Value

    If TypeOfIdea = 1 Then

        If Globalvar.ReminderCount = 1 Then
            FormDesktop.ReminderList.Text += "#" + Globalvar.ReminderCount.ToString + "  " + NameOfItem + vbCrLf
        Else
            FormDesktop.ReminderList.Text += vbCrLf + "#" + Globalvar.ReminderCount.ToString + "  " + NameOfItem + vbCrLf
        End If

        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            FormDesktop.ReminderList.Text += "Due: " + DueMonth.ToString + "/" + DueDay.ToString + "/" + DueYear.ToString + ", " + _
            DueHour.ToString + ":" + DueMinute.ToString + vbCrLf
        Else
            FormDesktop.ReminderList.Text += "Due: " + "N/A" + vbCrLf
        End If

        FormDesktop.ReminderList.Text += "Added: " + SubMonth.ToString + "/" + SubDay.ToString + "/" + SubYear.ToString + _
        ", " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString

    ElseIf TypeOfIdea = 2 Then

        If Globalvar.TaskCount = 1 Then
            FormDesktop.TaskList.Text += "#" + Globalvar.TaskCount.ToString + "  " + NameOfItem + vbCrLf
        Else
            FormDesktop.TaskList.Text += vbCrLf + "#" + Globalvar.TaskCount.ToString + "  " + NameOfItem + vbCrLf
        End If

        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            FormDesktop.TaskList.Text += "Due: " + DueMonth.ToString + "/" + DueDay.ToString + "/" + DueYear.ToString + ", " + _
            DueHour.ToString + ":" + DueMinute.ToString + vbCrLf
        Else
            FormDesktop.TaskList.Text += "Due: " + "N/A"
        End If

        FormDesktop.TaskList.Text += "Added: " + SubMonth.ToString + "/" + SubDay.ToString + "/" + SubYear.ToString + ", " + _
        DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString

    Else

        If Globalvar.IdeaCount = 1 Then
            FormDesktop.IdeaList.Text += "#" + Globalvar.IdeaCount.ToString + "  " + NameOfItem + vbCrLf
        Else
            FormDesktop.IdeaList.Text += vbCrLf + "#" + Globalvar.IdeaCount.ToString + "  " + NameOfItem + vbCrLf
        End If

        FormDesktop.IdeaList.Text += "Due: " + "N/A" + vbCrLf

        FormDesktop.IdeaList.Text += "Added: " + SubMonth.ToString + "/" + SubDay.ToString + "/" + SubYear.ToString + ", " + _
        DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString

    End If

    Me.Hide()
    FormDesktop.BringToFront()

End Sub
```

Comment: We should never need to ask for you to post the relevant code.

Comment: Also, selected text will be highlight blue in Windows unless you've messed around with your theme, so something being highlighted in yellow indicates that you are selecting text and setting the `SelectionBackColor`, so there's definitely code of yours involved here.

Comment: Youre absolutely right, this was a silly lapse of logic on my part. thanks

Comment: Update: I was wrong. I initially suspected you to be right and I checked my code and I WAS infact using selectionbackcolor. Ill show you the code
(see edited original post, sorry for not initially including it)

Comment: Just to clarify, this has not yet been resolved and im still stuck. Like I said I am in line with Jims suggestion already

Comment: Preserving any existing formatting cannot be done by assigning the Text property.  You'll have to use AppendText() to append or assign SelectedText to insert.

Comment: yes! thank you very much, I appreciate it